# SQL Server Integration Services(SSIS) coding competition

Tags: ssis

Sorry to ask this kind of question. If you people feel that it is not 100% technical or is violating the SO rules, please close this but after answering the question.

Is there any site that helds SQL Server Integration Services(SSIS) competition?

I searched in google(with the string "ssis competition") but with no result.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by competition? It makes no sense. Are you looking for solutions implemented using SSIS?

Comment: By competition I mean somewhat similar to say tsql challenges or TopCoder, GoogleCodeJam etc.

Comment: but SSIS isn't something that you would associate with 'competitions'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no competitions in SSIS that I know of.